# Detect whenever click event is fired in fully transparent window

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a transparent controls and window where I can click through as it would not even exist. My question is: Is it possible to detect whenever click event is fired no matter where on the screen I click, while the wpf applicaton is running? 
The reason why I need this is because I'm making an agent that will collect all information about actions made by user. Any suggestions, hacks, tricks will do.

Comment: If you are downvoting then at least explain why...

Comment: you can do it with background worker, write code of counting click of mouse or any keyboard events , write to a log file like text file or anything on it your application runs in background and any event perform that capture by background worker and writes it to any text file or anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create an event hook so that you could snoop all system wide messages before they are dispatched to the target window. Check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information...

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is the thing that I needed @Phil Wright, great! Also found a useful tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C